# Filter with dropdown <select> instead of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, list.js

I'm trying to filter by select dropdown using List.js

My example is working fine with radio buttons. But I would like to replace them with a select list.

I tried changing this html

```
<label>
  <input class="filter" type="radio" value="Blvd" name="address" id="address-all" /> Boulevard
</label>
<label>
  <input class="filter" type="radio" value="Blvd" name="address" id="address-boulevard" /> Boulevard
</label>
```

to this

```
<select>
  <option class="filter-all" type="radio" value="all" name="address" id="address-all" selected> 
    All
  </option>
  <option class="filter" type="radio" value="Blvd" name="address" id="address-boulevard">Boulevard
  </option>
</select>
```

and changed all instances of *checked* to *selected* in the .js

```
    var options = {
    valueNames: [
        'name',
        'address',
    ],
};
var userList = new List('users', options);

function resetList() {
    userList.search();
    userList.filter();
    userList.update();
    $(".filter-all").prop('selected', true);
    $('.filter').prop('selected', false);
    $('.search').val('');
};

function updateList() {
    var values_address = $("input[name=address]:selected").val();
    console.log(values_address);
    userList.filter(function(item) {
        var addressFilter = false;
        if (values_address == "all") {
            addressFilter = true;
        } else {
            addressFilter = item.values().address.indexOf(values_address) >= 0;
        }
        return addressFilter
    });
    userList.update();
}
$(function() {
    $('input[name=address]').change(updateList);
    userList.on('updated', function(list) {
        if (list.matchingItems.length > 0) {
            $('.no-result').hide()
        } else {
            $('.no-result').show()
        }
    });
});
```

But so far this isn't working. Thanks for any help with this.

Here is a fiddle with the original code: https://jsfiddle.net/6tht5pyk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7pkq23ty/

Simply change the selector from `$("input[name=address]:selected").val();` to `var values_address = $("select").val();`

And off course bind the event to the `select` element: `$('select').change(updateList);`

And it goes without saying that it's recommended to add an ID to your `select` element and using it in your selectors, instead of using `$('select')` - I used it to make the least amount of changes to your code.